# Is there a difference between 「まだ食べたり、飲んだりしています。」and 「まだ食べたり、飲んでいたりします。」?

Tags: て-form

Is this ungrammatical?

> 「飲んでいたりします」

Comment: There are two differences here: (i) whether to have -ている on the verbs or on 
する, (ii) whether the two verbs should be symmetric. Do you mean to ask both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you should always use 食べたり飲んだりしています, which is the correct way to apply the progressive ている to both verbs. Compare:

> 彼女は食べたり飲んだりしています。
>   She is eating and drinking.
>
> 彼女は食べたり飲んだりします。
>   She (will) eat and drink.
>
> [?] 食べたり、飲んでいたりします。
>   [?] She eats and is drinking.